# Page finish loading, load in jQuery content via Jquery .load, execute jQuery elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I want to be able to load in content (containing elements depending on jQuery) after main page has finish loading, the content will be retrived from another page on my site (div). How do I then get those element depending on jQuery to execute (work)?

How do I make these different jQuery elements to work with some easy method after they being loaded into the main page? I dont know much about jQuery, it would be great if I could just ad/edit a function on the scripts to make them work after inload, but ofcurse its propably more difficult than that. In the passed days I have tried initialize the different object that loads in but notice that it was quite difficult with complicated scripts.

The page load in new content like this (selectbox):

```
<select id="selectbox"> 
<option>1</option>
</select>
```

jQuery code to the selectbox:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
$("#selectbox").change(function(){ 
var selectedOption = $('#selectbox :selected').val(); 
$containerDiv = $('#div_that_will_get_content'); 
$containerDiv.html("");
        switch (selectedOption)
        {
        case "1":$containerDiv.load( "Page.html #div1 );break;
        }
return true;
}); 
});
```

Selected option in selectbox (1) collects data from Page.html #div1, then send the data to div "#div_that_will_get_content". So the div get loaded in after the main page have  finish loading.

Now if I want to put a jQuery element in this div and then load that div into the main page via the selectbox and to "#div_that_will_get_content", those elements dont work. Can anybody show a easy jQuery example with a smal explanation how the script was written from the begining and what you changed to make it work after it was loaded in?

Thanks.

Comment: Do i understand you correctly - you are successfully loading content into some divs after the page loads, but you can't figure out how to get JQuery events for those elements to work?

Answer (score 2):

Not entirely sure what you are needing but part of the answer lies in using the success callback of `load()`

```
/* define this cached elemn outside change handler so don't have to search DOM each time*/
$containerDiv = $('#div_that_will_get_content');

$("#selectbox").change(function() {
    /* val() of select is same as searching for selected option val() but less code*/
    var url = 'Page.html #div' + $(this).val();
    $containerDiv.load(url, function() { 
         /* new ajax loaded html exists you can run code here*/
        $containerDiv.find('#someOtherDiv').doSomething()
    })

});
```

API Reference: http://api.jquery.com/load/

If your problem relates to binding events to elements that will be loaded any time in the future such as click handlers, you can delegate these in your page load script using `on()`

```
$(document).on('click', '.className', function(){
     doSomething();
})
```

Comment: if you are wanting to run a plugin would have to call it from inside the success callback